# Calling method inside another method in javascript?

Tags: javascript, methods

I am having a JavaScript namespace say

```
A={

  CA: function() {
    this.B();
  },
  B: function() {
    var test='test';
    var result='t1';

    C: function() {
      this.test='test1';
      .....
      .....
      return 'test1';    
    }

   result=this.C();  
   return result; 
  }
}
```

Now when I am executing such code it is giving that TypeError: this.C is not a function. Can somebody tell me why it is so. I know it is something related with lexical scoping but am unable to understand this.

Comment: Sorry, I am a new user and posted the first question, don't know how to post questions. I will keep this in mind now onwards. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is that when `this.C()` is executed inside the function referred to by `B`, `this` refers to the object that contains `B`, that is, object `A`.  (This assumes `B()` is called within the context of `A`)

The problem is, `C` does not exist on the object `A`, since it's defined within `B`. If you want to call a local function `C()` within `B`, just use `C()`.

EDIT:
Also, I'm not sure what you've posted is valid JavaScript.  Specifically, `B` should be defined this way, since you can't use the object:property syntax within a function.

```
B: function()
{
  var test='test';
  var result='t1';

  var C = function()
  {
    this.test='test1';
    return 'test1';    
  }

 result=C();  
 return result; 
}
```

Comment: I think you are correct and I also did the same way finally (made the function and called it directly from the outer function) after banging my head to make this.C working.

Answer (score 30):

You have to be careful when you use *this* to identify anything in Javascript because each time you change scope "this" changes.

Assigning the 'this' reference to it's own variable helps get around this.

```
var a = new function() {
    var self = this;

    self.method = function() { alert('hiya'); };

    var b = function() {
        this.method(); // this isn't 'a' anymore?
        self.method(); // but 'self' is still referring to 'a'
    };

};
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

I am actually surprised that your code doesn't give you error on the 'C:' line.

Anyway, your syntax to define a function is not correct. Define it using the var keyword. Also, notice that I created the 'closure' so that the function C can access 'this'. See the code below:

```
A={

  CA: function()
  {
    this.B();
  },

  B: function()
  {
    var test='test';
    var result='t1';

    var self = this;
    var C = function()
            {
              self.test='test1';
              .....
              .....
              return 'test1';    
            }

   result=C();
   return result; 
  }
}
```

If you want to assign C to 'this' object, you can also do:

```
A={

  CA: function()
  {
    this.B();
  },

  B: function()
  {
    var test='test';
    var result='t1';

    var self = this;
    this.C = function()
             {
              self.test='test1';
              .....
              .....
              return 'test1';    
             };

   result= this.C();
   return result; 
  }
}
```

Comment: You won't be able to use 'this' because 'this' is a keyword and you do need to create the closure. Also, because I am defining the 'self' as a local variable, it won't impact the global object.

Comment: yeah sorry, I realised my dumbness, and hence deleted my comment :-( But Yes now i agree with your answer. +1 for putting up with me too :-)

Answer (score 2):

Solution for calling methods from another method.  (Essentially the pointer "this" must be assigned to a variable and the new variable used in place of this.)

```
 function myfunction(){
    var me = this;

    me.method1 = function(msg){ alert(msg); }

    me.method2 = function(){ 
       me.method1("method1 called from method2"); 
    }
 }

 var f as new myfunction();
 f.method2();
```

This example shows how one can call a method from within another method or from outside using an instance of the function.